# Can't create database in rails getting started guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Making my way through the standard Rails "getting started", I find that when I try to execute "rake db:create", I always get the error

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: attitude
  username: attitude
  password: ***
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: attitude
  username: attitude
  password: ***
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: attitude
  username: attitude
  password: ***
  host: localhost
```

i18n shows up in gem list i18n. Bundle show has i18n installed at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.0 I've seen some related questions around stackoverflow that seemed to be the result of using sudo bundle install. I tried creating a new rails project and carefully NOT using that command, but to no avail. Do I need to entirely reinstall rails, or is my Ubuntu install ruined, or what?

Comment: I ran into similar issues due to using sudo, i just started from scratch with the full ruby/rails installs.  I hope you have better luck

Comment: If you just want to get started with rails, forget about mysql for now and stick to sqlite. If you really want to have mysql, you should use the mysql2 gem like mentioned in the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: @StefanH could you offer a little further help? I'm new enough that I don't know how to get back to scratch. sudo apt-get purge rails was not enough, and I don't know what else to remove.

Comment: Use rvm.  Seriously, there is no end of trouble for someone new to rails trying to get a stable environment up and running when they are sudo installing gems.  Time that you spend learning rvm will pay you back ten-fold by never having to deal with problems like this.  https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Thanks. It was a long road, but rvm did end up being easier.

Comment: Not sure if those were just examples but you will want to use different databases for development and test (and production, too, if on the same host). For example, you won't want your production database being erased when you run your tests. (I'm restating what's in the comment in your code.)

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo gem uninstall i18n`. Then do a `bundle install` again (without sudo).